How to store ratings in a Windows Media Player Playlist?
I define a playlist in Windows Media Player, then set a rating to a song, close it, open it again. And the rating is gone.
Is there a way to "save" the rating, so the rating of the songs is as I rated them when reopening Windows Media Player?
Or better to use a another application for playing music (including playlists, rating, etc.)?

Yes, Windows Media Player is archaic, better to use any other app, at least 10 popular modern ones exist

Any suggestions for something simple and intuitive? Just installed e.g.  winamp but it is far from intuitive...

Ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/unanswered with exact reqiuirements

Windows Media Player is obsolete. You should replace it with any other supported media playing program, such as VLC Media Player, which will likely have the features you need. Unless you have a specific reason for listening to locally stored music, you can switch to a streaming service like Spotify, too.
